# I am trying to generate pdf in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript, pdf

```
<button class="print" (click)="generatePDF()">Generate PDF</button>
```

Generate PDF Code

```
generatePDF(): void {
    const element = document.getElementById('mainPrint') as HTMLElement;
    const imgWidth = 210;
    const pageHeight = 295;

    html2canvas(element, { scale: 2 }).then((canvas) => {
      const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
      const pdf = new jsPDF();
      const imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
      let heightLeft = imgHeight;
      let position = 0;

      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - pageHeight;
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
        if (heightLeft > 0) {
          pdf.addPage();
        }
      }

      pdf.save('page.pdf');
    });
  }
```

After clicking on "generate PDF," the PDF is being generated, but the first 4-5 pages are coming out blank, and on the next page, the content appears, but even that entire content is not being displayed.

Comment: Are you gettting base64 value to generate PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the extra space, but its not perfect, maybe you can refine it from here!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ChildComponent],
  template: `
  <div id="mainPrint">
  <app-child/>
  </div>
    <button class="print" (click)="generatePDF()">Generate PDF</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  generatePDF(): void {
    const element = document.getElementById('mainPrint') as HTMLElement;

    html2canvas(element, { scale: 2 }).then((canvas: any) => {
      var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

      var imgWidth = 210;
      var pageHeight = 295;
      var imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
      var heightLeft = imgHeight;
      var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // landscape
      var position = 0;

      /* addImage explained below:
          param 1 -> image in code format
          param 2 -> type of the image. SVG not supported. needs to be either PNG or JPEG.
          all params are specified in integer
          param 3 -> X axis margin from left
          param 4 -> Y axis margin from top
          param 5 -> width of the image
          param 6 -> height of the image
      */

      doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;

      while (heightLeft >= 0) {
        position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
        doc.addPage();
        doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
        heightLeft -= pageHeight;
      }

      doc.save('page.pdf');
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-k4vifg?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: I have add page screenshot for your reference
```
https://buddhabowl.in/test/screen.png
```
I have added your code, but now the first pages are not appearing blank, but 10 pages are being generated and the data that is on the first page is appearing on all pages.